# Vegalite Keep Most Recent Data (Filter Transform)

Tags: vega-lite

I have the following dashboard:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "description": "Domain Breakout Breakout",
  "width": "container",
  "title": {
    "text": ["Build number by service name"],
    "align": "center",
    "dy": -10,
    "fontWeight": "bold",
    "color": "#4f597a",
    "fontSize": 13,
    "font": "Montserrat,sans-serif"
  },
  "config": {"axis": {"grid": true, "tickBand": "extent"}},
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "service": "service1",
        "build": 5555,
        "env": "dev"
      },
      {
        "service": "service2",
        "build": 5555,
        "env": "test"
      },
      {
        "service": "service3",
        "build": 5555,
        "env": "staging"
      },
      {
        "service": "service4",
        "build": 5555,
        "env": "prod"
      },
      {
        "service": "service4",
        "build": 5225,
        "env": "prod"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"pivot": "env", "value": "build", "groupby": ["env", "service","build"]}
  ],
  "mark": "text",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "env",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": "descending",
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelFontWeight": "bold",
        "labelColor": "#4f597a",
        "labelFontSize": 20,
        "labelPadding": 20,
        "orient": "top"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "service",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "sort": {"field": "service", "order": "descending", "op": "sum"},
      "axis": {
        "title": null,
        "labelAngle": 0,
        "labelFontWeight": "bold",
        "labelColor": "#4f597a",
        "labelFontSize": 10,
        "labelPadding": 5
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "rect",
      "width": 1000,
      "encoding": {
        "fill": {
          "legend": null,
          "field": "build",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"range": ["#ecf9ff", "#c6efff", "#7ad9ff", "#42caff"]}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "fontSize": 8,
        "font": "Montserrat,sans-serif",
        "align": "center"
      },
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "build"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a use case in which new data is inserted with the same service name and env name but with a different build number. In this case:

```
  {
    "service": "service4",
    "build": 5555,
    "env": "prod"
  },
  {
    "service": "service4",
    "build": 5558,
    "env": "prod"
  }
```

The issue is the cell [service4][prod] has to layer the "old" value and the new value.
Is there an option in vega to get the last inseted value or something similar?

Link the dash: [Link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABE2yGrIAEAIXVwkAazYNMFq7fuZFIAO41l9NCChymEgmcOruOpiCcGigmHAAHm6oANog5gw0gsqmsgwITKGmTACephChxDRQcDlICNEAukpIwmR6-nCycWFKysVo-ACMAAxKAGaBAOpwNGRYfkxsWe4Bgmxh6ADEACxjYgCcAOwo44EAyjQAXtGogwDMp11+ALKB5erqSJgKEEiyEPx3jQxiAAL5KAKyMazGIgJDxGgQWFkTTKNCYdQMOBKHRQGzmP5o9AJOJPUHglRfFCoUDEFpYpEpUDvSrVPwsqpwQbuJgZZaoMSCsRKTrEPyqMXg5kVTnsmXVABMPL5RKFwpAor8cQgbilIA5bPQBrgd2VmVVQpFsjFRqCtFkZDBCml6lZN318rg2zN-LVVptIBw6jYaL1xrlrs53qUvPNaCFAA5-X4gyGwQ0KRi-hAJuoEGhkqAcDRiGwkhrre46YIsQsVe4UfYcCUCxWxUpwzH6xmmiBkOobFqSe5OgFlCZHTSQPFYdC4Py2+Fijh3etx7IWu4ZOpy6poJ1147mgjGbE6FE0LlBIIlIIkAVBABBB0X1CjEB3h8AMSmMzm5cWZZb3vecAGElnWPwdj2I4Tg-EDBB-LoLmuNAFXfT95wABSQZRDzQ991hoTpy0wNgcDBCl+inOcF07EBMGXVd1HXTcO3WJJQFookPUjNklDXUJxTUapZHwgSKKNPInThE9YQiV8rxveCH2fMhXwwhCkMwaZZnmdBALRYCH3AtYNhAaCDmOdxMMQ84rhuEZjOw3D8IFckKTvYohKZPskAHPwrCgNwlC8HwYDQEZhnfUcQwnWdMkEWEojIA9LwYa9xmIhdYyAhimL8ABHBg-giL4S2iDsoBaG5QE+B0blSTY4CgMZ9jGEElE2KAADY4A6zqLOOZR2sGnYFWqjqQAzDznT8gKp0Ylch0SdwJmQhy0CTEB1vLV4uneT5vl+f5AVCYF3BaWZ2lE7oZNitzYmHGjsp43LQ3JDMgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of joinaggregate and filter transform to get the max of build number. i.e. it will filter out the lower values. e.g.

```
 {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "max", "field": "build", "as": "MaxBuild"}],
      "groupby": ["service"]
    },
    {
      "filter":"datum.build >= datum.MaxBuild"
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABE2yGrIAEAIXVwkAazYNMFq7fuZFIAO41l9NCChymEgmcOruOpiCcGigmHAAHm6oANog5gw0gsqmsgwITKGmTACephChxDRQcDlICNEAukpIwmR6-nCycWFKysVo-ACMAAxKAGaBAOpwNGRYfkxsWe4Bgmxh6ADEACxjYgCcAOwo44EAyjQAXtGogwDMp11+ALKB5erqSJgKEEiyEPx3jQxiAAL5KAKyMazGIgJDxGgQWFkTTKNCYdQMOBKHRQGzmP5o9AJOJPUHglRfFCoUDEFpYpEpUDvSrVPwsqpwQbuJgZZaoMSCsRKTrEPyqMXg5kVTnsmXVABMPL5RKFwpAor8cQgbilIA5bPQBrgd2VmVVQpFsjFRqCtFkZDBCml6lZN318rg2zN-LVVptIBw6jYaL1xrlrs53qUvPNaCFAA5-X4gyGwQ0KRi-hAJuoEGhkqAcDRiGwkhrre46YIsQsVe4UfYcCUCxWxUpwzH6xnnSBJGwTEgyCi+HEC6A2Dg-Mh4u5oXB+SBY8tmoyQM94ek46CmiBGwxm-0Uh7I2ye6BoYJuuKvnlKMvsgA+AC8pmUt4QlA38S3yx3SmQdQbC1El3E6AJlBMR0aRAWcYPnRdNRxYocHddZINkFp3BkdRy1UaBOgwx1mgRRlYjoKI0FyQRBCUQQkAKQQAEEHUo1BRhAejGIAMSmGY5nLRYV04hiFwAYSWdY-B2PYjhOESePOK4bgVDiuIXAAFJBlCItBVKUdYaE6ctMEnMEKSPC8jMXTsQEwFC0PUDCsI7dYkishciRPN13HQ0JxTUapZF0gypyNPInThUjYQiNjqNohSFxYsg2LU0TBF4rpplmeZ0CEtE6PSiS1g2EAZIOY53HUjKlOuNARkKxitJ0qD43JCl6OKfymRAQDgPQKwoDcJQvB8GB6uGSarQg1r4MyQRYSiMhCKohgaPGayvIfcIHL8ABHBg-giL4S2iDsoBaG5QE+B0blSTY4CgMZ9jGEElE2KAADY4Fet6yuOZQXr+nYFQu16QAzdrez6mLdvQOJEjnWqbiTEAJiedBXi6d5Pm+X5-kBUJgXcFpZnaILrwpcCQ1m2JQLmzy623ckMyAA)

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks a lot!